# Advanced archive url structure (category, tag and date)

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, tags, archives

Is it possible to create a permalink structure like this:

```
mysite.com/category/books/tag/read/2010/01
```

Or at least something like this:

```
mysite.com/category/books/?tag=read&year=2010&month=01
```

To elevate this question even further, would it be possible to do it for custom post types and taxonomies as well? Something like this:

```
mysite.com/movies/actor/john-cusack/genre/thriller/2010/01
```

Answer (score 1):

[Yes, it's possible](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries). Use custom query variables, declare rewrite rules to [organize permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries#Permalinks_for_Custom_Archives).

For example, one can rewrite this URI:

```
/movies/bruce-willis/2011
```

to this one:

```
/index.php?post-type=movies&actor_tax=bruce-willis&requested_year=2011
```

(using [WP_Rewrite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/))

You need to "declare" your own "query variables" and use them in your own archive template.

Comment: Well, yes, I know that I should do something like that. But right now I am stuck at how should I mix and match custom post types with custom taxonomies. Ie, I can view custom post type yearly archive like this: /movies/?year=2010 and I can view custom taxonomy yearly archive like this /actor/bruce-willis/?year=2010 - but is there a built-in way to mix those two together (remember - "actor" is a taxonomy that may be used for other post types as well). Something like /movies/actor/bruce-willis/?year=2010?

Comment: No, there is no built-in way to mix those things. I've updated my answer a bit.